# Javascript if else issue

Tags: javascript

I have a div that I want to change color based on the int value in the div, but for some reason it doesn't change the color based on the if else statement I wrote. Instead no color appears. Why is that?

```
<div id="test">66</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");

if (testDiv<50) {
    testDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#900000';
} else if (testDiv > 49 && testDiv < 75) {
    testDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9933';
} else if (testDiv > 74) {
    testDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#00CC00';
}
```

Comment: Why would `testDiv` be a number, or in any way comparable to a number, it's clearly an element

Comment: You probably want `parseInt( testDiv.innerHTML, 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to check the element's innerHTML but comparing with the element itself. Try:

```
var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
var value = parseInt(testDiv.innerHTML);
if(value<50){
    testDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#900000';
}
else if(value>49 && value <75){
    testDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9933';
}
else if(value>74){
    testDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#00CC00';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're treating the element like a number.  You want to retrieve the element's content and convert it to a number.

```
var testDivValue = parseInt(testDiv.textContent, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've passed the HTML object into the if statement instead of it's actual value. You can use **innerHTML** property in order to get the content within the HTML element.

```
var test = document.getElementById("test"); // element by id
var testContent = test.innerHTML;           // the value of inner HTML content
```

Once you have stored the value in testContent variable, you can do whatever you want with it ;-)

```
    // Check if value of inner HTML is less than 50
    if(testContent < 50) {
      alert("true, do whatever you want.");
    } else {
      alert("false");
    }
```

I hope you find this useful,

Thanks.